# How to combine values of multiple fields in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How to combine values of multiple fields in doctrine?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
        $qb->where('article.visible = 1')
            ->select('article.id', 'article.slots_type', 'article.skill', 'article.type', 'article.views')
            ->innerJoin('article.categories', 'category')
            ->addSelect('category.title AS categories')
            ->orderBy('article.published_at', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

I tried use concat and groupBy, but it didn't give the right result

I have arrays

```
{
        "id": 710,
        "slots_type": 2,
        "skill": "2",
        "type": "1",
        "views": 1362,
        "categories": "strategy",
    },
    {
        "id": 710,
        "slots_type": 2,
        "skill": "2",
        "type": "1",
        "views": 1362,
        "categories": "seo",
    },
```

I expected

```
{
        "id": 710,
        "slots_type": 2,
        "skill": "2",
        "type": "1",
        "views": 1362,
        "categories": "strategy, seo",
    },
```

Comment: What did your groupBy additional parameter look like? Also, your results both have the same `id` ?

Comment: @Darren `->groupBy('categories')` or `->groupBy('category.title')`